# data integration practice key field handling

Tags: sql-server

Seeking thoughts and advice in addressing a customer request.  We're working in an existing database that contains primary keys but no foreign keys, which won't change.

- The request is for us to integrate data from outside sources which
  may contain duplicate values in the data.

  The data is from a records-management system, so key id values will
  increase with each record collected.

  The key fields, for the most part, are decimal(22,0).

  This is a daily ETL load of a relatively small amount of data, so
  performance isn't the most important concern.

**Is it better to prefix, suffix, or use some other strategy to create unique key values that can be traced back to the source?**

For instance, if the max existing value were 123456789, is it a good idea to prefix 100000 for external site A, 110000 for external site B, etc?   We've batted a few ideas about as a team and there seems to be pro's and con's with everything we can think of.  Not seeing much guidance on the web.

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Answer (score 1):

*Generally* it's better to have a separate field tracking whether the data is from A or B which is either part of your primary key or a supplementary index/constraint where you use a surrogate identity/auto-increment field as the primary key.

Among other things, this makes it easier to later do things like table partitioning or conditional indexes.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO that's a design anti-pattern. You're ascribing special meaning to internal database keys. Bad idea. Also if you ever did hit the 10,000 limit you're completely stuffed. I know you think you won't... but you might and it will be a catastrophe.

The normal pattern (again in my experience and opinion) is to add a `SRC_System` and a `SRC_Key` field with a unique index/constraint on them. These are used to track where the record came from.

In addition to these two new fields, you also have your original primary key in this table which is an internal key used by the system.

This design allows any number of additional systems with any range of keys to be added to your system.

The only challenge then is working out

1. How to merge - i.e. if two systems have records representing the same thing
2. How to add additional reference data if required